# Angularjs directive ng-click not triggering

Tags: angularjs

Here is my plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/U5WiZzhX31ifux33enYh

I'm writing a in-place editor directive. It works as expected first time but subsequent times Save or Cancel buttons does not work. Why is that?

In plnkr when I click Save or Cancel 2nd time, it does nothing but in my local dev environment it reloads page.

I'm angular newbie, appreciate your help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you remove the editor element from the DOM you will have to recompile the template before adding it again, or otherwise you will loose access to the scope.

Change your `show` function to something like this:

```
function show(){        
    editor = $compile(template)(scope);
    element.after(editor);
    element.hide();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was really simple! I had a feeling that I was losing binding but I got confused since the template was coming up every time; didn't know I was losing scope.